# Terminal not recognizing commands

Tags: terminal

My terminal is not recognizing the majority of commands. It won't recognize ls, ruby, python, brew, and a few others. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What does the prompt look like? What is your $PATH? The more information you can provide, the easier it is for others to help you troubleshoot. Best wishes!

Comment: My $PATH is ’/usr/local/bin:??

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like an issue with your `PATH`, run

```
/usr/bin/echo $PATH
```

My guess is that is going to be missing the required directories

```
export PATH=$PATH:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
```

Then try again

The `PATH` variable is the list of directories that will be searched when executed by the shell; this variable will not persist between bash sessions - and should be set in your `~/.bashrc` file.

```
echo "export PATH=$PATH:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin" >> ~/.bashrc
```

In your shell, *bash*, the `.bashrc` file will automatically be sources on terminal creation.